# How do I prevent empty checkout fields from being validated on page load?

Tags: magento2, validation, magento2.3.5, amasty

I am using Magento 2.3.5 and Amasty's "One Step Checkout" module. Amazon Pay is also present.

When viewing the checkout page, it seems something is trying to validate the `<input>` fields even though the user hasn't entered anything:

[image]

Is this something anyone has encountered before?